# Identifying 'undefined' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a large block of JavaScript that is wrapped in a try-catch block. It is rather complicated as it is loading stuff that was previously set in local storage. Because of that, I can't really provide a code sample. However, I'm trying to learn if there is a good way of identifying "where" or "what" is 'undefined' in this code block.

Does anyone know of some solid JavaScript / debugging tools to help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Um, your browser's built-in dev tools? If you want static code analysis, [JSLint](http://jslint.com) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com).

Comment: Hope the code breaks and comes in catch block. Catch the exception and log it your console. Firebug will give the exception object and you can get the exact detail I believe.

Comment: Set a breakpoint. Step through the code. Watch the variables. Confirm your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(typeof variableName)
```

And you'll see which one is undefined

Answer (score 2):

As d4rkpr1nc3 pointed out using `typeof` is a good solution, but you should worry not only about `undefined` but for `null` too, because `typeof null` returns `object`.

So the most likely way to do this is using a function like this:

```
function Type(variable) {
    if(variable === null)
        return 'null';
    return (typeof variable);
}
```

This way you could see if it is null undefined or other type.

Answer (score 0):

Chromes development tools are great for stepping through Javascript code. Simply press F12 in your browser on the page then jump to the scripts tab.

You can click anywhere on the left hand column (where the line numbers are) to set breakpoints and go through the code step by step with F8 -> F10 (the controls are in the top right).